# can't scroll control-sidebar in adminlte

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, adminlte

I'm using adminlte v3.1.0 in my project. I have problem in my control-sidebar. I can't scroll the sidebar after add class layout-fixed in tag body.

I want the sidebar fixed. But still can scroll the content inside there.

I'm sorry for my bad english. Thanks before.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

add `overflow-auto` to the `control-sidebar`

AdminLTE is based on bootstrap, which has a `overflow-auto` class

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `overflow-y:scroll;` in the div

Documentation for [CSS Overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)

Comment: Thanks it's work if height: 600px. But when i set to height:100% it's not work.

Comment: @NurOktaviani Did you Try `Overflow-y`?